# Ajax call using element created by ajax is not calling

Tags: jquery, ajax

**IN below code ,  created using ajax is not working for another ajax**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".hi").click(function(){
        $.ajax({url: "demo_test.txt", success: function(result){
            $("#div1").html(result);
        }});
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({url: "demo_test.txt", success: function(result){
            $("#div1").html('<button class="hi">'+ result + '</button>');
        }});
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>

<button>Get External Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

When i tried to click button created by ajax. and no response is shown..

Comment: You don't need two `ready`.

Comment: even though not working

Comment: `$("#div1").on('click', '.hi', function(){`